# Self-hosted Plugins & Themes store with auto-updates?

Tags: plugins, themes, updates, e-commerce

I'm looking for a way to self-host a WordPress Plugins/Themes store (ideally at no cost — I am but a poor developer!) with the following features:

- Sell Plugin/Theme downloads
- Auto-updates for sold extensions with WP Admin updater
- Managed with interface rather than pushing files

Nice-to-haves would be:

- Product gallery
- PayPal support
- License keys
- Managed inside WP Admin

Googling and searching SE has been unfruitful so if anyone knows a way to do the above please let me know!

Comment: [WooCommerce Software Add-on](http://www.woothemes.com/products/software-add-on/) and [Easy Digital Downloads](https://easydigitaldownloads.com/extensions/software-licensing/) both have a software licensing extension that will do what you are asking. Both options also have plugins for accepting PayPal. In total you could get your store set up for <$200. Consider it an investment in your business.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the software plugin for Easy Digital Downloads! A bit disappointing that I can't find anything with auto-updates for free though!

Comment: Well, developers like to get paid for things that take them a lot of time to build, provide a lot of functionality, and/or allow you to make money... all of which I can sympathize with. [WP Updater](http://github.com/groveld/wp-updater) is free and I've seen several tutorials on the subject, but you won't get license keys or any kind of payment processing with that.

Comment: I do understand the hypocrisy of what I'm asking for (a way to sell my software using software I got at no cost) but I'm sure many people would like a low-friction way of selling their work. WP Updater looks pretty good so I'll give that a go! Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you post saying you don't think it exists but I should look into things like WP Updater then I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Compared to a brick and mortar store, $200 is pretty low friction, imo. You can sell your software via WooCommerce or EDD, but you can't do license keys and updates without paid extensions. And assuming you aren't selling your software for pennies, you should make your investment back fairly quickly. Good luck!

Comment: This question if we ignore the recommendation is extremely broad, you need to break it down, which should be done as part of your specification of what it needs to do and how it needs to do it. Without doing that you're going to face major issues on a development, practical, business, finance, marketing, and management level. Each bullet point alone in your question is a whole collection of super broad questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only free solution that I  know of is [WP Updater](http://github.com/groveld/wp-updater). However, this only handles automatic updates for plugins that are self-hosted. It does not handle any product sales or license keys.